# Trigger with GROUP BY error! (ORACLE DATABASE)

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table ORDER_HISTORY and I want after insert on it , the customer_id and the sum of totalcost based on the customer_id to be inserted to the MAIN_ORDER

ORDER_HISTORY table:

```
History_id   |  customer_id | totalcost
---------------------------------------
      1      |     1000     |    100
      2      |     1000     |    200
      3      |     2000     |    50
      4      |     2000     |    50
```

and I want after the trigger fire, the Main_order to show these data:

MAIN_ORDER table:

```
 customer_id | order_price
 -------------------------
    1000     |  300
    2000     |  100
```

I have created the following trigger but I have an error message

```
CREATE TRIGGER triggerHIS
AFTER INSERT ON ORDER_HISTORY FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
INSERT INTO MAIN_ORDER (CUSTOMER_ID,ORDER_PRICE)
SELECT CUSTOMER_ID, SUM(TOTALCOST) as ORDER_PRICE
FROM ORDER_HISTORY
GROUP BY CUSTOMER_ID;
END;
```

the error message is:

```
One error saving changes to table "PR"."ORDER_HISTORY":
Row 4: ORA-04091: table PR.ORDER_HISTORY is mutating, trigger/function 
may not see it
ORA-06512: at "PR.TRIGGERHIS", line 3
ORA-06512: at line 1
```

Comment: You can't refer to the table which caused the trigger to fire.  Hence, your trigger is invalid.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply, I'm new to the SQL, can you please explain some more detail for me?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, in general you are right, however there is an exception see https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/29244/why-am-i-not-getting-a-mutating-table-error-in-trigger

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Can't agree with you, for ordinary triggers, yes, you are right, but there is compound trigger in Oracle, designed exactly for this cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this cases, to avoid error `table mutating` oracle have `compound trigger`.
You can write your trigger in this way.

```
create or replace trigger TR_ORDER_HISTORY

   for insert on ORDER_HISTORY
   compound trigger

   type t_recs is table of number index by pls_integer;

   pt_Ins t_recs;

   li_Ins pls_integer := 0;

   after each row is
   begin
      li_Ins := li_Ins + 1;
      pt_Ins(li_Ins) := :new.customer_id;

   end after each row;

   after statement is
   begin
      for li in 1 .. pt_ins.count loop

         update MAIN_ORDER
            set ORDER_PRICE =
                (select sum(TOTALCOST)
                   from ORDER_HISTORY
                  where customer_id = pt_ins(li)
                  group by customer_id)
          where customer_id = pt_ins(li);

         if sql%rowcount = 0 then
            insert into MAIN_ORDER
               (CUSTOMER_ID, ORDER_PRICE)
               select customer_id, sum(TOTALCOST)
                 from ORDER_HISTORY
                where customer_id = pt_ins(li)
                group by customer_id;
         end if;

      end loop;

   end after statement;

end;
```

Answer (score -1):

You can *maintain* the values using a trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER triggerHIS
AFTER INSERT ON ORDER_HISTORY FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
    v_cnt := int;
BEGIN
    SELECT COUNT(*) INTO v_cnt FROM MAIN_ORDER WHERE CUSTOMER_ID := NEW.CUSTOMER_ID;

    IF V_CNT > 0 THEN
        UPDATE MAIN_ORDER
            SET ORDER_PRICE = ORDER_PRICE + :NEW.TOTALCOST
            WHERE CUSTOMER_ID := :NEW.CUSTOMER_ID;
    ELSE
        INSERT INTO MAIN_ORDER(CUSTOMER_ID, ORDER_PRICE)
            SELECT :NEW.CUSTOMER_ID, :NEW.TOTALOST
            FROM DUAL;
    END;
END;
```